# TypeORM get one side of a many to many relationship

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have got two entities: `User` and `Organisation`. These entities have a Many-to-Many relationship with each other. (A user can belong to multiple organisations and an organisation has multiple users.)

I have an endpoint `/organisation/:id/members` this endpoint should return only the users belonging to the organisation of `:id`.

I have created a query as follows:

```
    const members = await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder(Organisation, 'org')
      .where('org.id = :orgId', { orgId })
      .innerJoinAndSelect('org.members', 'member')
      .select('member')
      .getMany();
```

This returns an empty array, except when `getRawMany` is used. Then it returns the following:

```
[
  {
    "member_id": 1,
    "member_email": "example@example.com",
    "member_firstName": "John",
    "member_middleName": "",
    "member_lastName": "Doe"
  }
]
```

I would like to know how I get `getMany()` to return `User` entities.

**Update:**
I have the following example which does work. However, it requires the user to give the joinTable a name.

```
await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder(User, 'user')
      .innerJoinAndSelect(
        'organisation_members',
        'member',
        'member.userId = user.id',
      )
      .where('member.organisationId = :orgId', { orgId })
      .getMany();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER:**
My entities were setup incorrectly. I specified my ManyToMany relationship like this (incorrect!):

```
@ManyToMany(type => User)
members: User[];
```

Because this is a bi-directionaly relationship, I must specify on what field the user has the relationship towards the organisations:

```
@ManyToMany(
  type => User,
  user => user.organisations,
)
  members: User[];
```

And my User entity has:

```
@ManyToMany(
  type => Organisation,
  org => org.members,
)
organisations: Organisation[];
```

Use the TypeORM Query Relation Builder to get all members.

**Updated once again:**

```
return getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .relation(Organisation, 'members')
      .of(orgId)
      .loadMany();
```